# C#.NET : How to set arabic or other languages' characters as access keys for a textbox control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multilingual, access-keys

Till now, I was using my software in English language only, now it is being converted to multi-languages, so all the access keys are being dead while computer language is set to other than English, I want to use my shortcut access key ***ALT + F*** in Arabic? How will I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Microsoft guidelines:

> Keyboard layouts change according to culture/locale. Some characters
>   do not exist in all keyboard layouts. When assigning shortcut-key
>   combinations, make sure that you can reproduce them using
>   international keyboards, especially if you plan to use the
>   shortcut-key combinations with the Windows 2000 MUI (Multilanguage
>   User Interface).
>
> Because each culture/locale may use a different keyboard, consider
>   using numbers and function keys (F4, F5, and so on) instead of letters
>   in shortcut-key combinations.
>
> Although you do not need to localize number and function-key
>   combinations, they are not as intuitive for the user as letter
>   combinations. Some shortcut keys may not work for each keyboard layout
>   in a particular culture/locale. For example, some cultures/locales use
>   more than one keyboard, such as Eastern Europe and most
>   Arabic-speaking countries/regions.

Comment: Hey cristallo, thank you for your answer, so should I consider that I can't use ALT + F combination as an access key while Arabic or any language other than English is set?

Comment: you have two option: define culture agnostic keys like F1,F2, ... or define different keyboard shortcut  for each culture. It is your choice... the right solution probably depends by the context. If you have to support a lot of different cultures then I suggest you to follow the culture agnostic keys approach

Comment: Your last comment seems the end of my search campaign, should I try to look deeper into this, or this is it? agnostic keys would be my solution I guess.

Comment: The culture agnostic key has the cons of being less intuitive.

Comment: Yeah but I don't see any other option here. Well thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

The access key can be assigned separately from the control text.

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox" 
    AccessKey="A" 
    Text="arabic label" 
    runat="server"
/>
```

Further reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.accesskey(v=vs.110).aspx

This may not be the official "best practice", but technically it will work.

Comment: Hey dlatikay, thank for your time, I've gone through your link, that's perfect, but I want something else, I want to use ALT+F when computer language is set to Arabic or any other than English. is it possible?